# cannot access an element by document.GetElementById("") inside javaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

this is the sample code in which "hello world" is not displayed.
   `

```
<p>This is example </p>

<button id="myBtn" onclick="function1()">Try it</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function function1(){
document.write("hii");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: He doesn't need too. He is calling it when he clicks on the button.

Comment: `document.write` overwrites the entire document. On the next line, everything is gone, including your element

Comment: Don't use [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write): _"Note: as `document.write` writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document."_

Comment: i just used it to see if the function is called or not. excluding document.write dosent solve my doubt.

Comment: Try what I put in my answer.

Comment: ok, now it worked . need to learn more about document.write(). thanks @Andreas

Comment: thanks @Oqhax it worked

Answer (score -1):

You have to store the `document.getElementById` inside a variable. Try this,

```
<p>This is an example</p>

<button id="myBtn" onclick="function1()">Try it</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function function1(){
    document.write("hii");
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo")
    demo.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no need to do that.

Comment: Check @adeneo's comment on the OP's question, that's why I downvoted you.